# Resize two verical divs in angular based on drag of middle div placed

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have two container divs as follows, up on dragging to the top/bottom on the marked div below, need to resize both the divs. I need to do this in an angular 6 application

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have already tried, and exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Did you use splitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some types of Splitters, you can try:

1. Angular splitter (commonly used)- use this command-  **npm i angular-split** for installation and follow the example for implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-split-simpler-example
2. Kendo splitter of Telerik UI - use this command  npm i @progress/kendo-angular-layout
   Follow the link for futher details:
   https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/splitter/panes/